# Hyper link not working on iPhone4/4s

Tags: jquery, css, ios4, hyperlink

We are using the jquery bxslider on our home page, but for some reason the hyper links within the slide elements don't work on iPhone4/4s. if you click on a link nothing happens.

Everything works fine on all other mobile devices and desktop.

our website is www.millenniumshoes.com

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: when i go there, it looks like it is the nivo slider not the bxSlider

Answer (score 0):

when i go there, it looks like it is the nivo slider not the bxSlider

try giving your anchor tags a **specific height**, nivo.css line 16.. you are using **height:100%;** which will **not** render the height..

when i debug your anchor tags, they calculate at **zero**.. try adding a specific height (using css or javascript) to your anchor tags that matches the same height as your image.

---

i dont see a height on your img tag .. what about adding a **height:auto** to your img rule to make it responsive:

jquery.bxslider.css **line 18**

```
.bx-wrapper img {
    display: block;
    height: auto; /* add this so the image is responsive based on its parent */
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

also test to see if you add a height to that anchor tag if that helps any after testing adding the height:auto to **line 18** in jquery.bxslider.css

Comment: Hi PAPAFRESH, thanks for your reply, but the bxslider is below the nivo slider. The nivo slider works fine, but the anchor tags within the bx slider don't work ONLY on the iphone 4/4s.

Comment: Hi Thanks again for your reply. I did that but to change. I don't understand why this would happen only on the iPhone4... If the issue is CSS related, I think I would have the same issue on most devices and browsers instead of only iPhone4.... I think it must be a js issue some where that I'm missing.